# Why is this threejs sphere not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this 3d sphere like halfway done. Its just working pretty slow on desktop, and doesnt even run on mobile. Could one of you guys take a look, and let me know what im doing wrong.

heres the threejs code

```html
 window.log = function()
{
 if (this.console)
 {
  console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
 }
};

// Namespace
var Defmech = Defmech ||
{};

Defmech.RotationWithQuaternion = (function()
{
 'use_strict';

 var container;

 var camera, scene, renderer;

 var sphere;

 var mouseDown = false;
 var rotateStartPoint = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
 var rotateEndPoint = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

 var curQuaternion;
 var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
 var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
 var rotationSpeed = 2;
 var lastMoveTimestamp,
  moveReleaseTimeDelta = 50;

 var startPoint = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
 };

 var deltaX = 0,
  deltaY = 0;

 var setup = function()
 {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  var info = document.createElement('div');
  info.style.position = 'absolute';
  info.style.top = '10px';
  info.style.width = '100%';
  info.style.textAlign = 'center';
  info.innerHTML = 'Pick you favorite color';
  container.appendChild(info);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.y = 150;
  camera.position.z = 500;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // Cube

  var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 200, 200);

  
  
  
  
  
  
  var material  = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  material.map    = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/color.jpg');





  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, material);
  
  sphere.position.y = 100;
  scene.add(sphere);


  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

  animate();
 };

 function onWindowResize()
 {
  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 }

 function onDocumentMouseDown(event)
 {
  event.preventDefault();

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);

  mouseDown = true;

  startPoint = {
   x: event.clientX,
   y: event.clientY
  };

  rotateStartPoint = rotateEndPoint = projectOnTrackball(0, 0);
 }

 function onDocumentMouseMove(event)
 {
  deltaX = event.x - startPoint.x;
  deltaY = event.y - startPoint.y;

  handleRotation();

  startPoint.x = event.x;
  startPoint.y = event.y;

  lastMoveTimestamp = new Date();
 }

 function onDocumentMouseUp(event)
 {
  if (new Date().getTime() - lastMoveTimestamp.getTime() > moveReleaseTimeDelta)
  {
   deltaX = event.x - startPoint.x;
   deltaY = event.y - startPoint.y;
  }

  mouseDown = false;

  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
 }

 function projectOnTrackball(touchX, touchY)
 {
  var mouseOnBall = new THREE.Vector3();

  mouseOnBall.set(
   clamp(touchX / windowHalfX, -1, 1), clamp(-touchY / windowHalfY, -1, 1),
   0.0
  );

  var length = mouseOnBall.length();

  if (length > 1.0)
  {
   mouseOnBall.normalize();
  }
  else
  {
   mouseOnBall.z = Math.sqrt(1.0 - length * length);
  }

  return mouseOnBall;
 }

 function rotateMatrix(rotateStart, rotateEnd)
 {
  var axis = new THREE.Vector3(),
   quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

  var angle = Math.acos(rotateStart.dot(rotateEnd) / rotateStart.length() / rotateEnd.length());

  if (angle)
  {
   axis.crossVectors(rotateStart, rotateEnd).normalize();
   angle *= rotationSpeed;
   quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);
  }
  return quaternion;
 }

 function clamp(value, min, max)
 {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
 }

 function animate()
 {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
 }

 function render()
 {
  if (!mouseDown)
  {
   var drag = 0.95;
   var minDelta = 0.05;

   if (deltaX < -minDelta || deltaX > minDelta)
   {
    deltaX *= drag;
   }
   else
   {
    deltaX = 0;
   }

   if (deltaY < -minDelta || deltaY > minDelta)
   {
    deltaY *= drag;
   }
   else
   {
    deltaY = 0;
   }

   handleRotation();
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
 }

 var handleRotation = function()
 {
  rotateEndPoint = projectOnTrackball(deltaX, deltaY);

  var rotateQuaternion = rotateMatrix(rotateStartPoint, rotateEndPoint);
  curQuaternion = sphere.quaternion;
  curQuaternion.multiplyQuaternions(rotateQuaternion, curQuaternion);
  curQuaternion.normalize();
  sphere.setRotationFromQuaternion(curQuaternion);

  rotateEndPoint = rotateStartPoint;
 };

 // PUBLIC INTERFACE
 return {
  init: function()
  {
   setup();
  }
 };
})();

document.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 if (document.readyState === 'complete')
 {
  Defmech.RotationWithQuaternion.init();
 }
};
```

heres a running demo (only works on desktop)

http://wander.ventures/sphere.html

everything works as it should on desktop, although its a bit slow, but on mobile safari, i wasnt even able to move the sphere.

Comment: Running slow on a desktop is a really good hint at why it doesn't run on mobile.  If it has trouble running at full speed when it has lots of processing power and memory available, I wouldn't expect it to work at all when that power and memory is taken away.

Comment: Avoid the CanvasRenderer and switch to the WebGLRenderer.

Comment: hey jcaron, thanks for the tip. which part of the code would that be exactly? im still learning all this. thanks